# error when use filter(),map(),... in spark java api( org.apache.spark.SparkException )

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

i'm new in spark and
when i use filter of spark in java api, i get this error(if collect() all of table it's correctly worked and i can see all of data get from cassandra.) i checked master and workers version are same and when application start in web ui of spark i can see it but:

```
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 0) / 6]
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 2) / 6]
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 4) / 6]
```

> 2017-08-28 16:37:16,239 ERROR TaskSetManager:70 - Task 1 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
>   2017-08-28 16:37:21,351 ERROR DefaultExceptionMapper:170 - Unexpected error occurred
>       org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Method onRequest of interface org.apache.wicket.behavior.IBehaviorListener targeted at
>   org.apache.wicket.extensions.ajax.markup.html.AjaxLazyLoadPanel$1@e7e7465
>   on component [AjaxLazyLoadPanel [Component id = panel]] threw an
>   exception     at
>   org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:268)
>     at
>   org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.invoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.invokeListener(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:248)
>     at
>   org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.respond(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:234)
>     at
>   org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:895)
>     at
>   org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
>     at
>   org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:265)
>     at
>   org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:293)
>     at
>   org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:261)
>     at
>   org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:203)
>     at
>   org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:284)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:258)
>     ... 29 more
>
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Panel me.SparkTestPanel could not be constructed.   at ...
>
> Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent
>   failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 10, 21.1.0.41, executor 1):
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: me.SparkTestPanel$1     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)   at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:67)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1826)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1713)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:80)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)   at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>
> Driver stacktrace:     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1435)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1423)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
>     at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1650)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1605)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1594)
>     at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:628)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1925)    at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1938)     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1951)     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1965)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1158)    at
>   org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.count(JavaRDDLike.scala:455)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.count(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
>     at me.SparkTestPanel.(SparkTestPanel.java:77)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     ... 39 more
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: me.SparkTestPanel$1   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)   at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:67)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1826)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1713)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:80)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)   at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     ... 1 more

And my code is :

```
import com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraJavaUtil;
import static com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions;
import static com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraJavaUtil.mapColumnTo;
import com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraRow;
import com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.rdd.CassandraTableScanJavaRDD;

import java.util.List;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;

import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form;

/**
 *
 * @author mohamadreza
 */
public class SparkTestPanel extends Panel {

    private Form form;

    public SparkTestPanel(String id) {
        super(id);
        form = new Form("form");
        form.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        this.add(form);             
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf(true);
        conf.setAppName("Spark Test");
        conf.setMaster("spark://192.16.11.18:7049");
        conf.set("spark.closure.serializer","org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializer");
        conf.set("spark.serializer","org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializer");

        conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "192.16.11.18");
        conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "7005");
        conf.set("spark.cassandra.auth.username", "user");
        conf.set("spark.cassandra.auth.password", "password");
        JavaSparkContext sc = null;
        try {
            sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
            JavaRDD<CassandraRow> cache = javaFunctions(sc).cassandraTable("keyspace", "test").cache();
            Long count = cache.filter(new Function<CassandraRow, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean call(CassandraRow t1) throws Exception {
                    return t1.getString("value").contains("test");
                }
            }).count();
            String a = count.toString();
        } finally {
            sc.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

And spark version 2.1.1 ,scala version 2.11,JAVA 8 and my pom.xml:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

I use docker for cassandra and spark nodes.(cassandra version 3.0)
Can Any one help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem solved :)**

When you want use JAVA Api of Apache Spark you must Copy `.jar` (located in target directory in root of your project) of your project to `$SPARK_PATH/jars/` in each Spark node(master and workers).if your `.jar` is very large you can split ui and spark code  and only copy `.jar` of spark code project and use this spark code in your ui project.

Comment: barik bar javan irani aziz